# Http2 need PageSpeed Module?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, http2, mod-pagespeed

We use ubuntu 14.04 and nginx 1.6.2, 
Recently, in order to use http2, I upgrade our server from Ubuntu to 16.04, nginx to 1.10.0, and efficacy is very well.

And I test to compile nginx with pagespeed module(1.11.33.4), and compare

1. http2
2. http2+pagespeed

but I found that option2 is slower than option1(**ex: option1: 7s and option2: 13~14s**),
I try following setting:

```
pagespeed on;

# Needs to exist and be writable by nginx.  Use tmpfs for best performance.
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;

# Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed handler
# and no extraneous headers get set.
location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
  add_header "" "";
}
location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }
```

or add more one line:

```
pagespeed RewriteLevel CoreFilters;
```

but both slow, is there any problem in my setting config? or it is http2 and pagespeed module not working well?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the value suggested by docs page:
https://modpagespeed.com/doc/https_support